# Subscript with matrix generated by assign()

Tags: r, matrix, cat, subscript

I assigned a matrix to a name which varies with *j*:

```
j <- 2L
assign(paste0("pca", j,".FAVAR_fcst", sep=""), matrix(ncol=24, nrow=12))
```

This works very neat. Then I try to access a column of that matrix

```
paste0("pca", j,".FAVAR_fcst", sep="")[,2]
```

and get the following error:

> Error in paste0("pca", j, ".FAVAR_fcst", sep = "")[, 2] : 
>       incorrect number of dimensions

I've tried several variations and combinations with `cat()`, `print()` and `capture.output()`, but nothing seems to work. I'm not sure what I have to search exactly for and couldn't find a solution. Can you help me?

Comment: what about `get(paste0("pca", j,".FAVAR_fcst", sep=""))[,2]`

Comment: How about to read the help page of `assign`, particularly the last part of the example?

Comment: Thank you, it would have been so easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` :

```
get(paste0("pca", j,".FAVAR_fcst", sep="")) # for the matrix

get(paste0("pca", j,".FAVAR_fcst", sep=""))[,2] # for the column
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

An other solution would be to combine `eval` and `as.symbol` :

```
eval(as.symbol(paste0("pca", j,".FAVAR_fcst", sep="")))[,2]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: mostly, another solution would be to put matrixes in a list!